# Pascal, вводить число n кол-во раз и сравнить полученные цифр и исходными

Tags: pascal

Составить  программу,  которая запрашивает  у  пользователя  любое  трехзначное  число  и 
меняет  его  порядок  цифр  на  обратный.  Сравнить  исходное  число  с  полученным.  Про-
грамма позволяет выполнить действия n раз. 
Вот написал программу и хотелось бы узнать как сделать чтобы можно было вводить число n количество раз и в конце он бы сравнил полученные числа с исходными

```
 var
      i,n:integer;
    begin
      repeat
        write('N = '); readln(n);
      until (n>=100) and (n<=999);
      writeln('Было введено число - ',n);
      writeln('_________________________');
      writeln('Перевёрнутое число - ',n mod 10,n div 10 mod 10,n div 100);
    end.
```

Comment: не надо сравнивать потом. написать цикл от 1 до N, ввести числои сравнить надо внутри цикла

Comment: Сравнить и что сделать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Число `n` необходимо ввести только один раз.
2. Сделать цикл с количеством итераций `n`.
3. Основные действия внутри цикла.
4. Для вводимого числа использовать отдельную переменную (пусть `m`).
5. Если не знаете как сразу сравнить к перевернутым числом, запишите его тоже в переменную (пусть `r`)

Отрицательное число тоже может быть трехзначным.